# Google Dataflow: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

when trying to run a large transform on ~ 800.000 files, I get the above error message when trying to run the pipeline.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
    PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());    
    GcsUtil u = getUtil(p.getOptions());

    try{
        List<GcsPath> paths = u.expand(GcsPath.fromUri("gs://tlogdataflow/stage/*.zip"));
        List<String> strPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(GcsPath pa: paths){
            strPaths.add(pa.toUri().toString());
        }           

        p.apply(Create.of(strPaths))
         .apply("Unzip Files", Write.to(new ZipIO.Sink("gs://tlogdataflow/outbox")));
        p.run();
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        //
    }
```

}

I thought thats exactly what google data flow is for? Handling large amounts of files / data?

Is there a way to split the load in order to make it work?

Thanks & BR

Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dataflow is good at handling large amounts of data, but has limitations in terms of how large *the description of the pipeline* can be. Data passed to `Create.of()` is currently embedded in the pipeline description, so you can't pass very large amounts of data there - instead, large amounts of data should be read from external storage, and the pipeline should specify only their locations.

Think of it as the distinction between the amount of data a program can process vs. the size of the program's code itself.

You can get around this issue by making the expansion happen in a `ParDo`:

```
p.apply(Create.of("gs://tlogdataflow/stage/*.zip"))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new ExpandFn()))
 .apply(...fusion break (see below)...)
 .apply(Write.to(new ZipIO.Sink("gs://tlogdataflow/outbox")))
```

where `ExpandFn` is something like as follows:

```
private static class ExpandFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void process(ProcessContext c) {
    GcsUtil util = getUtil(c.getPipelineOptions());
    for (String path : util.expand(GcsPath.fromUri(c.element()))) {
      c.output(path);
    }
  }
}
```

and by *fusion break* I'm referring to [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion) (basically, `ParDo(add unique key)` + `group by key` + `Flatten.iterables()` + `Values.create()`). It's not very convenient and there are discussions happening about adding a built-in transform to do this (see [this PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/pull/1036) and [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@beam.incubator.apache.org/msg01578.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much! Using your input I solved it like this:

```
public class ZipPipeline {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ZipPipeline.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
    PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());    

    try{
        p.apply(Create.of("gs://tlogdataflow/stage/*.zip"))
         .apply(ParDo.of(new ExpandFN()))
         .apply(ParDo.of(new AddKeyFN()))
         .apply(GroupByKey.<String,String>create())
         .apply(ParDo.of(new FlattenFN()))
         .apply("Unzip Files", Write.to(new ZipIO.Sink("gs://tlogdataflow/outbox")));
        p.run();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }

}

private static class FlattenFN extends DoFn<KV<String,Iterable<String>>, String>{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
      KV<String,Iterable<String>> kv = c.element();
      for(String s: kv.getValue()){
          c.output(s);
      }


      }

  }

private static class ExpandFN extends DoFn<String,String>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception{
      GcsUtil u = getUtil(c.getPipelineOptions());
      for(GcsPath path : u.expand(GcsPath.fromUri(c.element()))){
          c.output(path.toUri().toString());
      }
  }
}

private static class AddKeyFN extends DoFn<String, KV<String,String>>{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
     String path = c.element();
     String monthKey = path.split("_")[4].substring(0, 6);
     c.output(KV.of(monthKey, path));
  }
}
```